Iterating and saving files with new headers and names in bash
I'm trying to iterate over some subdirectory files, save the unique directory names to a string called "basename", then print the first and fourth columns to a new file that uses that basename and then add a header with the basename to those two columns.
I've gotten to:
for d in *_kallisto/ ; do
    basename="${d%_kallisto/}" 
    #echo $basename
    awk '{print $1,$4}' "$d"abundance.tsv > "$basename"_counts.tsv
    sed -i '1 i "$basename"\t"$basename"' "$basename"_counts.tsv
done

It's mostly working but two issues:

I get subfiles called "_counts.tsv" without the basename added.

The _counts.tsv files have the correct columns but the sed command header looks like:
 $basename       $basename
 target_id est_counts
 transcript/4818 2.80969
 transcript/4840 2897.99
 transcript/4868 33.588



Please help! Thanks in advance.
Note: I was able to fix it with this, first parsing the prefix using -v in awk:
for d in *_kallisto/ ; do
    pfx="${d%_kallisto/}" 
    #echo $pfx
    awk -v var="$pfx" 'BEGIN{print var"\t"var}
        {print $1,$4}' "$d"abundance.tsv > "$pfx"_counts.tsv
done


If you found a solution, you should post it in an Answer below, not in the question.

You did not specify, how the input files look like, i.e. how the columns are separated. Your attempt of using awk suggests that the columns are separated by one or more white-space characters (space or tab), but it's better to express this explicitly.

Running sed -i on a file you just created is always wasteful. If nothing else, pipe the command which created the file to sed so you don't end up writing essentially the same data to disk twice. But you can sometimes avoid sed entirely.

Don't name your variable basename as that's the name of a Unix tool, and you never need sed when you're using awk.
At least part of your problem is that your sed command:
sed -i '1 i "$basename"\t"$basename"' "$basename"_counts.tsv

has the sed script enclosed in single quotes and so the variables can't be expanded by the shell, that's why you see the literal strings "$basename" in your output file.
Try this (untested):
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob

for old in *_kallisto/abundance.tsv ; do
    pfx="${old%_*}"
    new="${pfx}_counts.tsv"
    pfx="$pfx" awk '
        BEGIN {
            FS = OFS = "\t"
            print ENVIRON["pfx"], ENVIRON["pfx"]
        }
        { print $1, $4 }
    ' "$old" > "$new"
done


Thanks for the suggestions, this didn't quite work. It generated files called "abundance.tsv_counts.tsv" that had headers that looked like: hant3_gill_kallisto/abundance.tsv
I was able to fix it using:
for d in *_kallisto/ ; do  pfx="${d%_kallisto/}"   #echo $pfx  awk -v var="$pfx" 'BEGIN{print var"\t"var}   {print $1,$4}' "$d"abundance.tsv > "$pfx"_counts.tsv done

Why are you using ENVIRON instead of just passing them as awk variables with -v? And ENVIRON requires you to export the variables.

@Barmar probably because you don't have to escape the backslashes in the filenames when using ENVIRON

What's the disadvantage of using the name of an executable program (basename, ls or whatever) as the name of a variable?

@user1934428 it makes your code easier to misunderstand and it becomes easier to make a mistake that leads to cryptic errors.

@RenaudPacalet it should be pfx="${old%_*}", fixed now.

@Julia I updated my answer to fix the setting of pfx.

@Barmar as @Fravadona says, -v interprets escape sequences by design so you'd have to add a caveat of "assuming on \s in your file name" if you were to use it in that script, and you don't need to export variables for them to be accessible in ENVIRON[], they just have to be in awks environment as pfx is in my code thanks to being set (again) on the same line as the call to awk with pfx="$pfx" awk '...'. See ENVIRON[] in how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script.

The following assumes that all *_kallisto/abundance.tsv are real files (no directories named *_kallisto/abundance.tsv). You can do almost everything with just awk:
awk '                        
  BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }
  FNR == 1 {
    b = FILENAME; sub(/_kallisto\/abundance\.tsv$/, "", b)
    f = b "_counts.tsv"; print b, b > f
  }
  { print $1, $4 > f }
' *_kallisto/abundance.tsv

This will not create an output file if an input file is empty, and it will work only as long as the number of files does not exceed the limit for the length of a command line. Note also that it will issue an error if there are no *_kallisto/abundance.tsv files.

Regarding your final approach
for d in *_kallisto/ ; do
    pfx="${d%_kallisto/}" 
    #echo $pfx
    awk -v var="$pfx" 'BEGIN{print var"\t"var}
        {print $1,$4}' "$d"abundance.tsv > "$pfx"_counts.tsv
done

doing {print $1,$4} in GNU AWK without setting OFS (output field-separator) earlier causes GNU AWK to use default, which is space. Someone tasked with further processing of .tsv file might expect 2 columns sheared by TAB and (after finding this is not case) curse anyone responsible for that.
Either use concat with "\t" like in BEGIN (this is acceptable if separator is etched in stone) that is
'BEGIN{print var"\t"var}{print $1"\t"$4}'

or set OFS to \t that is
'BEGIN{OFS="\t";print var,var}{print $1,$4}'

